# How to proceed for the following problem on real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a recursive sequence given by setting $$a_1>2, \quad a_{n+1}=a_n^2-2 \quad \text{for} \quad  n\in \mathbb{N}.$$ Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_1a_2\cdots a_n} = \frac{a_1-\sqrt{a_1^2-4}}{2}.$$

[Original image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfUqA.png)

By definition, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ increases to infinity. Moreover, we have $a_{n}^2-4 = a_{n-1}^2(a_{n-1}^2-4)$. Now to proceed from this step?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1. Let $A_n=\frac{a_{n}}{a_{1}\cdots a_{n-1}}$ then for $n\geq 2$
$$A_{n+1}-A_{n}=-\frac{2}{a_{1}\cdots a_{n}}.$$
Therefore the sum is telescopic.

Hint 2. Show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n=\sqrt{a_1^2-4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Based on your own conclusion
$$\prod_{k=2}^{n}{a_k^2-4\over a_{k-1}^2-4}=\prod_{k=2}^{n} a_{k-1}^2$$therefore$${a_n^2-4\over a_1^2-4}=(a_1\cdots a_n)^2$$